# Heketi - adding device with existing data

Tags: kubernetes, glusterfs, openshift-origin

I have an OKD cluster with GlusterFS as a storage class and Heketi as a frontend. Everything works fine till destroy of the Heketi database. Now I can't make any changes to the storage, I can't add new persistent volume. GlusterFS still works fine serving existing persistent volumes to pods.

I tried to recreate Heketi database with loading topology file but I think that Heketi is trying to create physical volume on LVM on device that already contains LVM with working GlusterFS. When I try to load topology I see following line in Heketi logs:

```
[kubeexec] DEBUG 2021/01/23 17:04:39 heketi/pkg/remoteexec/log/commandlog.go:34:log.(*CommandLogger).Before: Will run command [/usr/sbin/lvm pvcreate -qq --metadatasize=128M --dataalignment=256K '/dev/sdb'] on [pod:glusterfs-storage-vdm96 c:glusterfs ns:glusterfs (from host:okd-admdev-compute1 selector:glusterfs-node)]
```

Heketi client hanging on adding device to cluster and then got a timeout.

```
[root@heketi-storage-12-wn652 tmp]# heketi-cli topology load --json=topo.json 
Creating cluster ... ID: 6a65d3bce35760e5075db0cae6ed8e7e
    Allowing file volumes on cluster.
    Allowing block volumes on cluster.
    Creating node okd-admdev-compute1 ... ID: 7da6b2b1e4f9a723cfd769618ef36a51
        Adding device /dev/sdb ... Unable to add device: Initializing device /dev/sdb failed (failed to check device contents): timeout
    Creating node okd-admdev-compute2 ... ID: e63f5366838492219a8f929ee4cc67a7
        Adding device /dev/sdb ...
```

How to recreate Heketi database without reinitializing devices and reuse devices with existing data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no solution for this because Heketi cant recreate own database from LVM storage. But there is workaround for this.

1. First I made backup of all data on GlusterFS storage by mounting volumes with native client.
2. Destroy LVM storage.
3. Let initialize Heketi whole cluster from scratch.
4. Recreate volumes.
5. Mount volumes with native client.
6. Restore data. Make sure to restore all attributes.